# C# : Excel date FromOADate flips day and month

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, date, datetime

I'm reading date values from an excel file with format : (french format) "jj/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss" so it's : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

When trying to get this value in C# I get a double so I resolved it with the function fromOADate

but the problem is for a date like 04/01/2016 (January) I get it flipped to 01/04/2016, even if I set the format.

```
double dtvalue = xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2;                           
dateString = DateTime.FromOADate(dtvalue).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```

I've tried to change the format to :

```
dateString = DateTime.FromOADate(dtvalue).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```

and add this code in order to split it and set it again :

```
date = dateString .Split(' ');
string[] firstPart = date[0].Split('/');

day = int.Parse(firstPart[0]);
month = int.Parse(firstPart[1]);
year = int.Parse(firstPart[2]);

DateTime newDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);

newDateString = newDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " " + date[1];
```

It worked for some dates and for others it didn't work.

How can I solve this problem please ?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC5, C#, using Excel Interop

Comment: You can try to use us culture :  `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");`

Comment: I'll just add this instruction ? or I should do something ? beacause I tried and it still do not work, same result

Comment: Please clarify: Is the date correct in C#, and then incorrect when returned to Excel?  Or is it incorrect in C#?

Comment: It is correct in Excel but incorrect when returned to C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem related to EXCEL it flips dates, so as a solution I used `xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Text` instead of `xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2`.

Comment: I was straggling with this for years.
Such an easy fix

Comment: Now it messes up other dates.